Sending files from server to client using steamworks
Is it possible to send a file using Steamworks? I'm currently using Facepunch's Wrapper for the Steamworks API, but I'm having trouble knowing how I should send a file, whether I should split it across messages or is there a specific way to send it all at once

Why would you want to? Your game should collect and send data points as it is generated.
